# Importing data to google analytics with R

Tags: r, import, google-analytics

I would like to automate the data upload to GoogleAnalytics with R, but cannot find the way to do it.

So far I have done this:

1. Get google auth token based on [googleAuthR](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR) package:

`token <- Authentication$public_fields$token`

2. Generate url to the upload endpoint:

   `url.template <- "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/%1$i/webproperties/%2$s/customDataSources/%3$s/uploads"
   url <- sprintf(url.template, account.id, web.property.id, data.source)`
3. Call POST using httr package:

   httr::content_type("text/csv")
   httr::POST(url = url,
        body = list(y = httr::upload_file("ga-product-import.csv")),
        config = token,
        encode = "multipart"
        )

So far I am getting 400 response.

I also tried this:

```
f <- gar_api_generator(url,
                       "POST",
                       data_parse_function = function(x) x)
f(the_body =  list(y = httr::upload_file("ga-product-import.csv")))
```

but getting this error:

> Error : No method asJSON S3 class: form_file Error in
>   the_request$status_code :    $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: What happens if you run one of the examples from `googleAuthR`?

Comment: @Hack-R I did not see any examples with file upload, can you give a link

Comment: @Hack-R I have tried `gar_api_generator` but that does not seem to work also.

Comment: There is cost data import in googleAnalyticsR now https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAnalyticsR/blob/master/R/custom_data_source.R

Answer (score 1):

The library [googleAnalyticsR](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/) depends on googleAuthR, and has a cost data upload function with help found at `?ga_custom_upload`

Comment: thank you for this. Unfortunately, I did not have a chance to try it yet. I will try to get back to this soon.

Comment: Went back to this and managed to upload custom data to GA, thanks a lot!